# Does this chord function as a 13 chord?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, harmony, analysis

In Debussy's *La Fille aux Cheveux de Lin*, there is this passage:

[image: Debussy]

(Debussy: Préludes Livre I, No. 8, bar 24)
The piece is in Gb major.

This first chord is probably a I chord. But since it has that extra Eb, does it mean it's a I13 chord, despite the fact it has no other notes from that extension? Or is it just a normal I chord with some decoration?

The other option is that it's vi7b chord. Is this more likely?

Comment: Why can't is just be a 6th chord?  There is no dominant 7th which would be the signature of 13.

Comment: This isn't a sixth / thirteenth chord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every single chord in this measure is an Ebm7, in various inversions and voicings.

Comment: Gb maj 6 = Eb min 7.

Comment: @ggcg, it is not possible to understand the function of this chord without the surrounding music.

Comment: I interpreted the OP as asking about the chord itself.

Comment: So did I, and the more standard interpretation would be Ebm7.

Comment: They are quite the same, just inversions of each other,  But okay.

Comment: I'm not sure whose answer to accept. Imo, this seems like the more likely one.

Answer (score 0):

A 13th chord usually has a dom 7 in it.  Without that you will not hear the typical 13th chord sound.  It is however a maj 6 chord {1, 3, 5, 6}.  Sometimes the 5th is omitted but doesn't need to be if the voicing avoids a maj 2nd, e.g. {5, 1, 3, 6}.